# PHP Warning: stristr(): Empty delimiter in file.php on line 25

Tags: php, xml, shoutcast

I am trying to figue out why my php error log is giving me this error.
PHP Warning:  stristr(): Empty delimiter in filename.php on line 25

Now I have looked at the line and none of the variables are empty. So any help with this would be great, as I can not find anythign wrong with it. Also it does work but just giving out an warning. I want to see if I can fix it.  Below is the entire code.

```
<?php
 if(!$db = @mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass"))
 die('<font size=+1>An Error Occurred</font><hr>Unable to connect to the database. <BR>Check $dbhost, $dbuser, and $dbpass in config.php.');

if(!@mysql_select_db("$dbname",$db))
die("<font size=+1>An Error Occurred</font><hr>Unable to find the database <b>$dbname</b> on your MySQL server.");

if (isset($dj)) {
$dj = NULL;
}

$query="SELECT * FROM currentdj";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $did = $row['dj'];
    $aliasa = $row['alias1'];
    $aliasb = $row['alias2'];
    $aliasc = $row['alias3'];
    // The following code should detect DJ by song title, for Podcast and Audio Fictions 
    if ((isset($aliasa)) && (stristr($song[0], $aliasa) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias1";
    $dj = $did;
    }
    if ((isset($aliasb)) && (stristr($song[0], $aliasb) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias1";
    $dj = $did;
    }
    if ((isset($aliasc)) && (stristr($song[0], $aliasc) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias1";
    $dj = $did;
    }
    // The following code should detect DJ by server title, for DJS and autodj
    if ((isset($aliasa)) && (stristr($servertitle, $aliasa) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias1";
    $dj = $did;
    }
    if ((isset($aliasb)) && (stristr($servertitle, $aliasb) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias2";
    $dj = $did;
    }
    if ((isset($aliasc)) && (stristr($servertitle, $aliasc) !== FALSE)) {
    $setby = "Alias3";
    $dj = $did;
    }  
}
?>
```

So I get this warning for all my If isset statements.

Comment: what does $song[0] resolve to?

Comment: $song[0] is the current song being played on the shout-cast server.
it is not empty as it echos out fine

Comment: Are you sure $aliasa is not empty?

Comment: $aliasa is data in the mysql db, they have data

Comment: @Joseph Scocca: you're making assumptions. Programming isn't about assumptions, but about facts. You want to solve your issue - work with facts and use `var_dump`

Comment: One of the parameters must be empty, that's the nature of the warning message you mentioned. I suggest you CONFIRM your assumptions AT RUNTIME.

Comment: @zerkms ok, is ther any diffrence in echo and var_dump ?

Comment: yes, echo is for strings. var dump will output the contents of a resource

Comment: var_dump() is more "raw" and will help in case the variable is just an empty string (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found out the issue. The warning are do because the page alone does php think the var is empty, but when you go to the main page it then loads the info into the vars and then it really is not empty, that is why it does work live on the website, but still getting warnings on the php error page, since this is the only error i get i decided to ignore it,

Thanks everyone for your thoughts